# How to generate a biphasic pulse in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am looking for an efficient way to generate biphasic pulse in MATLAB like the one in figure below. X-axis is time in seconds and amplitude is current from 0-20uA.
P.S. The signal is an input stimulation for an impedance meter.
[image]

Comment: Can you please specify the line encoding? I can't figure it out from your image.

Answer (score 1):

Specific example below. You can abstract into a function from there.

```
x = 10*ones(20,1);  % initialize to mid value
x(1+(2:6)) = 20;    % set the positive pulse
x(1+(8:12)) = 0;    % set the negative pulse
% the "1" offset is due to Matlab starting an array at index 1 (and not 0).
```